# How do I serialize an object into an XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class that is marked with DataContract attributes and I would like to create an `XDocument` from objects of that class. Whats the best way of doing this?

I can do it by going via an `XmlDocument` but this seems like an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can create an XmlWriter directly into the XDocument:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    // write xml into the writer
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSerialize);
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Comment: -1 Great step in the right direction, but lacks as a full answer to the question. Could you cover the actual serialization into the XDocument?

Comment: @Levitikon: I edited the answer to cover the serialization using DataContractSerializer.

Comment: This doesn't work. It returned an empty string for me...

Answer (score 3):

this is how i do it, which gives clean xml without all the namespace stuff in it,

```
 XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

        using (var writer = xdoc.CreateWriter())
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objecttoserialize.GetType());

            x.Serialize(writer, objecttoserialize);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```