# Convert object model to XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

Good day guys, How can i convert an object model to an xmldocument. this is my object:

```
var profile = new ProfileModel() 
                { 
                    xh="aa",
                    FirstName = "wolverine",
                    LastName = "wolverine2",
                    PhoneNumber = "66332214477",
                    Email = "wolverine@wolverine.com",
                    SourceSystem = "TY",
                    ID = "ty1002224"
                };
```

right now I'm doing it manually like this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("aa",
                                            new XElement("FirstName","wolverine2"),
                                            new XElement("LastName", "wolverine"),
                                            new XElement("PhoneNumber", "66332214477"),
                                            new XElement("Email", "wolverine@wolverine.com"),
                                            new XElement("SourceSystem", "TY"),
                                            new XElement("ID", "ty1002224")
                                            ));
```

but i want something more generic so i could use it to all of my object. Also, I have a case that I have a list of ProfileModel and need to convert it to xmldocument.

EDIT:
I want the output to be plain xdocument:

```
<aa>
  <FirstName>wolverine2</FirstName>
  <LastName>wolverine</LastName>
  <PhoneNumber>66332214477</PhoneNumber>
  <Email>wolverine@wolverine.com</Email>
  <SourceSystem>TY</SourceSystem>
  <ID>ty1002224</ID>
</aa>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the amazing XDocument class. This will use reflection and serialize all the properties.

```
// in System.Xml.Linq
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    // write xml into the writer
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType());
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSerialize);
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Source: [How do I serialize an object into an XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806095/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-into-an-xdocument)

Comment: good answer @b1tsh1ft. I still have a concern here though. i'm also getting the <ProfileModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Integration.Models"> element which i dont want. I added my desired output in the post. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the XmlSerializer class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx