# Add Serialized Structure To XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to add a serialized structure to an existing XML file. In the code below,

- I test if the file exists.
- If not I create it.
- If it exists I want to add a serialized structure (from a memory stream) to the file using the `.Add` syntax.
- When `xmlDoc.Add(xmlSerialized);` executes, it gets the below error

> "Non white space characters cannot be added to content."

What am I doing wrong?

```
try
{
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
    XmlSerializer xmlSerialized = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataClass.Task));
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    xmlSerialized.Serialize(memStream, taskStruct);
    xmlDoc.Add(xmlSerialized);

    bSuccess = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to fix issue as MemoryStream does not appear to be a valid type to pass in per [Valid Content of XElement and XDocument Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882(v=vs.110).aspx)**

I think the issue you're encountering is that you're trying to add the instance of `XmlSerializer` to the `XDocument`, rather than the serialized object contained in the `MemoryStream` `memStream`.

Since `MemoryStream` appears to be a type that cannot be passed in, try the `CreateWriter()` method of `XElement`, like this:

```
try
{
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
    XDocument newXml = new XDocument();

    using (var writer = newXml.CreateWriter())
    {
        // write xml into the writer
        DataContractSerializer xmlSerialized = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataClass.Task));
        xmlSerialized.WriteObject(writer, taskStruct);
    }

    xmlDoc.Add(writer);

    bSuccess = true;
}
```

Above code based on this answer:  [How do I serialize an object into an XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/806447/745969)

Comment: Adding memStream returns error non white space. I tried xmlDoc.Root.Add(memStream) and get this: 
     <Tasks>System.IO.MemoryStream</Tasks>

Comment: @IrvineCAGuy - Did you try the new example I posted?  It doesn't use MemoryStream, but uses the CreateWriter method on XElement to write the serialized object to an XElement, which you should then be able to add to the xisting XML document.

Comment: declaring XElement newXml = new XElement()  statement is not valid in System.Linq.XElement. It wants two arguments.  But your solution looks like it's getting close.

Comment: Oh, and  WriteObject is not defined for xmlSerialized.

Comment: @IrvineCAGuy - Ok.  I changed the code to match the example in the linked answer.  This uses an `XDocument` instead of an `XElement`, and `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`.  Give that a whirl.

Comment: Tim. Getting closer.  I get "Non Whilte space...on xmlDoc.Save(path).  Could it be my task.xml file?  It is created like this:

Comment: if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create new xml Task file
                try
                {                    
                    XElement tasks = new XElement("Tasks");
                    xmlDoc.Add(tasks);                    
                    xmlDoc.Save(path);

                    bSuccess = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Main.errorMessage = ex.Message;
                    bSuccess = false;
                }                
            }